# Import MinGW C++ DLL in C# or VC++

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, mingw, managed-c++

I have a MinGW DLL with source code(~20k lines) and I need to use some classes from this DLL in CLR. At first I tried to write Manged C++ wrapper class for C++ class(that I just copied from the source code) and refer to this class from C#. But there are differences of VC++ compiler and MinGW, hence the native code compiles with some errors! I have no no big experience in C++ and ASM and it produces some troubles.

Tell me guys, is there a way to import a MinGW class in VC++ or C#?

UPD:

Differences MingGW and VC++:

1. ASM invocation code like

`asm("fnstcw %0\n" : "=m" (cw) :  : "memory");

asm("fldl (%0)\n": : "r"(x): "st(7)"); };

asm("fstps (%0)\n": : "r"(x): "memory", "st");`

not compiles in VC++. I have never written assembler code harder than MOV AX, BX:)

1. It also executes fortran code and I don't understand how:)

Comment: Can you post some examples of the differences? Very hard to examine the errors if they are not provided.

Comment: the trouble you will find is if the MinGW dll relies on heavily GnuC types, you will need to import GNU header files into VC++ to use the dll. You might find it helpful to write a wrapper dll that uses a VC++ friendly interface, and use that within your managed project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few points:

1. You can't use C++ DLL, but you can use C DLL as any other native DLL.

   See: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs
2. About the code - it changes some FPU options so if you want to port it to C#/.Net
   you should first understand what it does.

Comment: about 1: could you suggest me manual how to use MinGW DLL in VC++ DLL? I never coded seriously on C++, but I know only one way to import DLLs: I have a .lib file and I write #pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib"). But I have no a lib file in the bin folder in the project!

Comment: See the link I had added in the answer's body